# Issue Reading Local Video File

Tags: python, opencv

I have opencv installed, but when I do the following:

```
import cv2
vs = cv2.VideoCapture('./video1.mp4')
ret, frame = vs.read()
```

`vs.isOpened()` returns `True` but `ret` always return `False` and frame is `None`.

Does anyone knows what would be the possible reason to this?

Comment: Could be that the file is corrupt, could be a typo in the name, could be that the relative path is incorrect.... hard to say without more info.

Comment: Hi @WilliamMiller thanks for the reply. I did the same in another environment, there are value for both ret and also frame, so i think the file is not corrupted. The path is also right, hence was wondering which part actually went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## cap.isOpened() vs cap.read()

People can open a book but it doesn't mean they can read the book if they don't know the language or the book is written in unknowing language so do computers...

As the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a9d2ca36789e7fcfe7a7be3b328038585) for isOpened() says:

> Returns true if video capturing has been **initialized** already.

[and for cap.read()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)

> cap.read() returns a bool (True/False). If frame is **read correctly**, it
> will be True. So you can check end of the video by checking this
> return value.

Comment: It seems to be because of the input video has audio (mpeg4 aac), once i remove the audio from the input video with ffmpeg, the ret returns True already. However, i tried installing different packages for the aac but it didnt work out. Currently, the environment is a ubuntu18.04 docker image on a ppc64le machine. Do you have any idea what need to be done to enable opencv to read video with audio without error? Thank you